# Could not open input file: composer.phar

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I am trying to install **zendframework** using composer tool in wamp server.

The following steps are done towards installation

1. I downloaded the Composer-Setup.exe file from composer page and got successfully installed.
2. I downloaded the **zendframework** and extracted inside the `c:\wamp\www\zend` folder
3. I executed the command for self update

   `php composer.phar self-update`

This line generates the error message: `could not open file composer.phar`

**how to resolve this error**

If I try the

```
composer.phar self-update
```

[image]

Comment: Just try `composer.phar update` command.

Comment: composer.phar is trying to open a file using installed software

Comment: try './composer.phar update' instead of 'composer.phar update' only

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The composer.phar install is not working but without .phar this is working.

We need to enable the openssl module in php before installing the zendframe work.

We have to uncomment the line **;extension=php_openssl.dll** from `php.ini` file.

composer use different php.ini file which is located at the `wamp\bin\php\php-<version number>\php.ini`

After enabling the openssl we need to restart the server.

The execute the following comments.

I can install successfully using these commands -

```
composer self-update
composer install --prefer-dist
```

[image]

Answer (score 105):

Use this :

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

This will install composer to the current directory so that you can use `php composer.phar`

Comment: This Works to install composer and set configuration proper for composer.pahr

Answer (score 28):

I was trying to install YII 2.0

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-alpha
```

I got the same error:

**Could not open input file: composer.phar**

Then i gave the full path of .phar like this:

```
php C:\ProgramData\Composer\bin\composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-alpha
```

and it worked.

Comment: composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-alpha or php composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-alpha

Comment: I was typing the `composer create-project -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install`command seen at `https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication` but it would give me the error message `Could not open input file: /home/stephane/programs/laravel-5.1.1/composer.phar`. So I tried with your syntaxt `php composer.phar create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application ...`and it worked fine.

Answer (score 13):

I am using Windows 7, and I got the same problem as yours while using Composer via cmd.

The problem is solved when I use

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton
```

instead of

```
php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton
```

Hope this is useful for people who got the same problem.

Comment: Had same problem but had to Additionally "cd" to the location where the composer.json file is located

Answer (score 8):

First try this: dont use the `php composer.phar [parameters]` simply use `composer [parameters]` if this doesn't work for you than try the rest. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Question already answered by the OP, but I am posting this answer for anyone having similar problem, retting to

> Could not input open file: composer.phar

error message.

Simply go to your project directory/folder and do a

```
composer update
```

Assuming this is where you have your web application:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/zendframework
```

change directory to it, and then run `composer update`.

Answer (score 5):

Initially, I was running php composer.phar self-update and got the same error message.

As a resolve, you should use composer command directly after install it.From the command prompt, just type composer and press enter.

If composer is installed correctly then you should able to see a lot of suggestion and command list from composer.

If you are up to this point then you should able to run  composer self-update directly.

Answer (score 5):

Try in command line:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Comment: This worked for me after I botched uninstalling composer. .... 1. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php .... then 2. mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 4):

dont use `php composer.phar self-update`
First go to Your project directory
simply use `composer.phar self-update`
This works for me

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed the same issue with below steps

1. Open project directory Using Terminal (*which you are using i.e. mintty* )
2. Now install composer within this directory as per given directions on https://getcomposer.org/download/

> php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
>
> php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'the-provided-hash-code') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
>
> php composer-setup.php
>   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

3. Now run your command.

Everything is working fine now because the `composer.phar` file is available within the current project directory.

```
Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/running-composer-returns-could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar/51907013#51907013
```

thanks

Comment: In principal the instructions here work.  However the latest version is slightly different.  Reference:  https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 3):

This is how it worked for me:

- Make sure composer is installed without no errors.
- Open "System Properties" on windows and go to the "Advanced" tab. (You can just press the windows button on your keyboard and type in "Edit the system environment variables`
- "Environment variables"
- Under "System variables" Edit "PATH"
- Click on "New".
- Type in: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar
- Close all folders & CMDs + restart you WAMP server.
- Go to whatever directory you want to install a package in and type in

  `composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton`

for example.

Answer (score 3):

If you go through the documentation, they have mentioned to use `php composer.phar`
*Link:* https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u

Don't use `php composer.phar`
only give `composer`

Command: `composer self-update`

It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

use

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="https://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Just add `https` instead of `http` in the URL. Though it's not a permanent solution, it does work.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be.. find the location of composer.phar file in your computer. If composer is installed successfully then it can be found in the installed directory.

Copy that location & instead of composer.phar in the command line, put the entire path there.

It also worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Just Use **composer install**

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to use `php composer install` in a local directory on my Apache server for a laravel project I cloned from Github.  My problem was I had already setup `composer` globally on my Ubuntu 18 machine. 
 Adding `sudo` instead of `php` started the install of a whole slew of packages listed in the `json.lock` file i.e. `sudo composer install`.