# Composer is not working

Tags: php, composer-php

I am new to Composer and trying to install a package via composer as

```
$ php composer require intervention/image
```

but i am getting

> Could not open input file: composer

error since i have just run my last composer command 10 mins ago. 
I don't now what is causing that problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar-error-in-symfony2-using-wamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably in your case Composer was installed [globally, as a stanalone application](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally).

Instead of

```shell
php composer require intervention/image
```

run

```shell
composer require intervention/image
```

Comment: i used to run my composer commands with php at the start of them and they were working properly. Not sure what has changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, then execute your command again.

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then you can use `composer` instead of `php composer ...`

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116960/global-installation-of-composer-manual)