# Mandrill in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, mandrill, laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5.2 , i want to add Mandrill to my project , i used this command :
php composer.phar require guzzle/guzzle:~3.9

and the result was :
Could not open input file: composer.phar

How to add Mandrill compose without change the old compose dependencies ?

Comment: First, it should just be `composer.phar require guzzle/guzzle:~3.9` - it does not need the `php` prefix you have shown above. Another thing to consider is whether you have you installed composer globally. Failing the suggestion above, what happens when you try `composer require guzzle/guzzle:~3.9` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar-error-in-symfony2-using-wamp)

Comment: I know that this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I just wanted to say that I recently tried Laravel 5.2 / Guzzle 3 / Mandrill and had endless problems. Then I changed to Guzzle 6 and it worked well. But, anyway, do what James has written above and then post a new question if you have any specific Guzzle or Mandrill issues.

Comment: i got this error : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - guzzle/guzzle v3.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: thank you , i just installed the curl

Comment: Mandrill just alienated most of their developer users with mandatory paid accounts and various other hassles. Would stay away for now. Try mailgun or amazon ses which still offer a free tier service