# Getting error during use of composer installation on windows

Tags: php

I have executed the following command on windows command prompt

```
folder path >php composer.phar install
```

Getting Error

> Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: Have you installed it first? Was it installed globally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Composer returns: "Could not open input file: composer.phar"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/running-composer-returns-could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar)

Comment: @RafałCz, I have not installed it globally now i have execute   following command folderpath > composer install .It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is trying to use composer which is not installed. It is not used to install composer. You have to install it using one of methods stated here:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

The other option is that your path to composer file is wrong, which can also be fixed by following documentation.

Comment: Thanks for information.It helps me to resolved my problem.