# Could not open input file [COMPOSER]

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-user-bundle

when i'm running this command : php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update

i'm having this error: Could not open input file.

i did some research on google and i can see that ***a lot of peopple had the same problem like mine***! but i don't find the way to solve it.

This is my path : `%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar`

i followed the instruction on those website but it doesn't help me :

http://www.naeemrana.com/technology/how-to-install-composer-dependency-manager-for-php-in-windows/

[Could not open input file: composer.phar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769980/could-not-input-open-file-composer-phar)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate issue: 

Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar-error-in-symfony2-using-wamp

Comment: use `composer` instead `composer.phar`.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update
```

run

```
composer require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update
```