# yii2 installation via composer - Could not open input file: composer.phar

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I am trying to install the `yii2` and after I installed the composer I tried to run `composer.phar` `global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`
it says :

> Could not open input file: composer.phar

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not input open file: composer.phar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769980/could-not-input-open-file-composer-phar)

Comment: You can gave the full path of composer.phar in your command or even reinstall composer with  `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php` and then run your original command

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of composer work correctly.

```
php composer.phar -v
```

Try

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

*I know probably you've figured it out by now but still I want to help.*
Make your `composer.phar` global so you can access it from anywhere. You can set path in environment variables or you can give direct path like below:

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

**Note**: I'm using Windows 8.1 and composer is installed in C directory.

Answer (score 0):

First of all install composer in your system Like windows system. you can download composer from this url https://getcomposer.org/download/. after install composer you can go to C:\composer check files for composer.phar and composer.bat files then copy both files and goto C:\xampp\php paste both files here and restart xampp then after that you can install yii2 [image]