# PHP executable cannot fine composer.phar

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php

Yesterday I created a laravel project using the command `php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel TestProject` which worked fine and the project was created.

Today I am trying to do the exact same but with a different project name and now I am getting an error in my console saying : `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

I have had a poke around on stackoverflow and seen a few answers with people saying to drop the `php` and `.phar` and just call the composer, but I still get the same error message just without the extension.

Unsure why it worked yesterday and not today, anyone know why? For reference I am on mac.

Comment: What is the location of your `composer.phar` in reference to the `path` from which you are running your command?

Comment: What operating system are you using? And do you have composer globally installed or do you use a local executable?

Comment: you should follow this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769980/could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar

Comment: @UmairKhan my composer has the same path as the command. Both are in the htdocs of MAMP

Comment: @Jerodev I am runnin MacOS, how do I check the composer is global or local?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670709/running-composer-returns-could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, Navigate to the directory you are creating the project in, in this case mine is htdocs then enter this command:

`php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

This will install it in that location.

Comment: Follow instructions fully for moving it into globally available location for executables. 
That way you will solve your problem for good. Otherwise you will download composer again and again. Read `Download` and `Getting Started` pages on getcomposer.org site. 
`Documentation` page won't hurt neither.