# cake php version Migration

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cake php 2.9 . Now I am trying to migrate it into 3.9 . When I run **php composer.phar require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:3.9.*"** it show's
Could not open input file: composer.phar

It is noted that my os is windows 10 and php version is 7.1.

Is there any dependency If I migrate this ? Thanks in advance

**My ultimate target is to go to php 7.1**

Comment: Make your life easier and get Composer with the [Windows Installer](https://getcomposer.org/download/). In any case, have you checked the migration guide? The ORM in CakePHP/3 is completely different, it's going to be quite more work than upgrading packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open input file: composer.phar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769980/could-not-open-input-file-composer-phar)